# Show that $\mathbb{I}_A$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $x_0$ is not a boundary point of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $A \subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{I}_A:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the indicator function of A. Show that $\mathbb{I}_A$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $x_0$ is not a boundary point of $A$. If $C$ is the *Cantor* set where is $\mathbb{I}_C$  continuous?

Well, I been struggling with this demonstration for a while, and I could only write down the definitions. Any suggestions would be great!

$\Rightarrow$] $\mathbb{I}_A$ is continuous in $x_0$ if $\forall$ sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n\longrightarrow x_0$ we have that $\mathbb{I}_A(x_n)\longrightarrow \mathbb{I}_A(x_0)$.

$\Leftarrow$] If $x_0$ is not a boundary point of $A$, it means that there exists $r>0, B_r(x_0)\cap A = \emptyset = B_r(x_0)\cap A^c$.

Comment: Your definition of "$x_0$ is not a boundary point of $A$" is incorrect. This doesn't imply that there is an open ball $B_r(x_0)$ that intersects neither $A$ nor $A^c$. In fact, that's impossible as every point of $\mathbb R$ is in either $A$ or $A^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_0$ is a boundary point of $SA$  then there exists a  sequence $(x_n)$ contained in $A$ converging to $x_0$ and a sequence $(y_n)$ contained in $A^{c}$ converging to $x_0$. Now $I_{A}(x_n) =1$ for all $n$ and $I_{A}(y_n) =0$ for all $n$. Henec $\lim_{x \to x_0} I_A(x)$ does not exist and $I_A$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

If $x_0$ is not  a boundary point then there is an open interval around $x_0$ which is completely contained in $A$ or an open interval around $x_0$ which is completely contained in $A^{c}$. Can you finish?

The boundary of the Cantor set $C$ is  $C$ itself since it is closed with no interior points.